# HTTP GET and POST from HTTPS domain

Tags: c#, ajax, http, https

OK, so the basics of what I'm trying to do is send info from an AJAX webpage to a local app via a HTTP listening port.  The web domain looks something like this --> https://coeus-dev.hosting.com:42122/Test/Example.html.  it has a Submit button which does pretty much this --> "xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:4012/USP?unique=1470771541298&RequestType=Foo", false);".

Using Fiddler I don't see any data come to the local host.  I'm assuming that CORS is involved here some how but that just a total guess.

Bottom line:  Why doesn't Fiddler see any traffic coming from the webpage to the localhost?

thanks!

Comment: you are doing a CORS request. different protocol, different port, different host, they're ALL a cross-origin violation.

Comment: Not sure why this question got down voted.  So CORS is the ONLY issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not only a CORS problem, but a mixed-content too:

**you can't make an http ajax request from an https webpage** because the browser will block it for security reason.

Comment: ok, so is there a way around this?  I can't change the webpage to http.

Comment: You can set up a kind of proxy: an https webpage on your server that call in back-end the unsecure http webpage, and then returns the result. So the JS calls your https webpage and don't have mixed-content or cross origins (CORS) issues.  Of course, it means you can't use cookies.